# What is considered an empty and root route in angular-ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

How does URL look like to translate into empty route in this example?

```
app.config(function($urlRouterProvider){
    // when there is an empty route, redirect to /index   
    $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/index');
})
```

Should it be like this `http://somedomain.com` without trailing hashbang or like this `http://somedomain.com/#` with trailing hashbang but without trailing slash?

And how does URL look like to translate into root route in this example?

```
app.config(function($urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.when('/', '/index');
})
```

Should it be like this `http://somedomain.com/#/` with trailing hashbang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out. The key is `$location.path()` and the regexps which come as a result of parsing `.when(expression` function call:

1. `.when(''` translates into `/^$/` regexp
2. `.when('/'` translates into `/^\/$/` regexp

And

1. for `http://somedomain.com` `path()` is `""` - empty string
2. for `http://somedomain.com/#/` `path()` is `"/"`

Then paths are simple matched against regexps.

It also depends on the [mode](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#hashbang-and-html5-modes) in which the angular is running, since `.path()` is determined differently depending on the mode.